# thumbnail with some text to the right?

Tags: css

I have a list like this:

```
<html>

  <head>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="testli.css">
  </head>

  <body>
      <ul id='grok'>
          <li>
              <img src='na' class='cimg' />
              <div class='cinner'>
                  <p>Title, max two lines.</p> 
                  <p>Some longish text, max two lines, causes problems when too long.</p>
              </div>
              <div style='clear:both'></div>
          </li>

          <li>
              <img src='na' class='cimg' />
              <div class='cinner'>
                  <p>Title</p>
                  <p>Some longish text here which may wrap some and cause problems..</p>
              </div>
              <div style='clear:both'></div>
          </li>

      </ul>

  </body>
</html>


// testli.css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#grok {
  list-style-type: none; 
  width: 200px;
}

#grok li {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: 5px; 
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}

.cimg {
  width:70px;
  height:44px; 
  float:left;
}

.cinner {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font:14px;
}
```

when the text in the p elements is short, the layout behaves as I want - the thumbnail and the text should appear as if they're in two separate columns. I'm basically looking to recreate the thumbnails youtube has for recommended items - thumbnail on the left, some text in another column to the right of it. Title and text each allowed two lines of text each.

If the text is too long, the cinner div gets placed below the thumbnail. What's the right way to force it to always be to the right?

Thanks

Comment: it'd be nice to include a link to your page, or a full test html page to plug in to a browser.

Comment: ok added full html / css for a test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by setting a min-height on the `<li>` and then absolutely positioning the image to the left of the title and description:

```
#grok {
   list-style-type: none; 
   width: 200px;
}

#grok li {
   position: relative;
   margin: 5px; 
   padding: 5px;
   min-height: 44px;

   /* min-height fix for IE6.  Ideally this would be in an IE6 only stylesheet */
   height: auto !important;
   height: 44px;

   background-color: lightgreen;
}

.cimg {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 70px;
   height: 44px;        
}

.cinner {       
   padding: 0 0 0 80px; /* Makes room for the image so it doesn't overlap text */
   font: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `max-width` to `.cinner` (if I don't mistaken - `max-width: 110px`).